# nowadays with verb or verb+ing form

Tags: verbs

Does anyone know why B is better than A ?

> A. Nowadays, public health is a topic that starts to get growing attentions.

-

> B. Nowadays, public health is a topic that is starting to get growing attention.

Comment: I cannot say I like any of them

Comment: This is a loaded question. Why do *you* assume B is better than A, and why do we have to agree?

Comment: Hi RegDwight, some native speakers corrected me. my original one is A, and he changed it to B

Comment: Cool. Notice that you get a better grade of answer if you ask a better grade of question -- i.e, a question **with context**.

Comment: Please add your comment to your question. Click on "edit" and you can *explain* why you said B is better. To be honest with you, B sounds clumsy. Why do you need "start" and "get" together? "Nowadays, public health is a topic that is getting increasing attention."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Nowadays* is a complex temporal adverb that means much the same thing as ***[Positive anymore](http://microsyntax.sites.yale.edu/positive-anymore)***.
That is, *Nowadays, `S`* asserts that `S` is true at the present time,
and also [presupposes](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/presuppositiontriggers.pdf) that there was a time in the past when `S` was false.

- *Nowadays, everybody carries a phone.*
- *Everybody carries a phone nowadays.*
- *%Any more, everybody carries a phone. *
- *%Everybody carries a phone any more. *
  (The '%' in front of the sentence means it's dialectal -- see the link for details)

This is the opposite of normal *any more* -- which is a [Negative Polarity Item](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf)
and therefore can appear only in a negative clause.
Normally, *Not `S` any more* asserts that `S` is false in the present,
and presupposes that `S` was true in the past.

- *Nobody wears a fedora any more.*
- *Nobody wears a fedora nowadays.*

But the reason why the second sentence is preferable to the first has nothing to do with *nowadays*.
*Start* is an active inchoative predicate, and therefore its use in the present tense
is interpreted in a [Generic](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/generics.html) sense. With a punctual predicate like *start*,
that would mean a **repetitive** sense, as in

- *The motor starts to sputter every time I press the accelerator.*

That is, the "present tense" *starts to get* is not used to refer to the present time;
the progressive *is starting to* is used instead.

Comment: Thank your very much for your comments. So it will sound like native speaker if I say "Nowadays people is starting to use smart phones" rather than "Nowadays people start to use smart phones"

Comment: _People_ ought to have a plural verb, since it's plural. So it's _Nowadays people **are** starting_. And it's *sound like **a** native speaker*. So I'm not guaranteeing that, sorry.